# Create a custom NestJs Decorator inheriting @Body() or @Param() decorator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm usin NestJs, and in many of my controllers I'm using :

```
@Post(":id")
public create(
    @Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id: number, 
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) myData: MyClass) {
        // ... 
    }
```

I would like to clean my code by creating a custom decorator, for instance:

```
@Bind() => @Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
```

or

```
@Id() => @Param('id', new ParseIntPipe())
```

then the code would be much more cleaner than before:

```
@Post(":id")
public create(@Id() id: number, @Bind() myData: MyClass) {
    // ... 
}
```

What is the correct way to inherit those decorators like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since decorators are just plain functions you can simply create a function that returns the called decorator:

*decorators.ts*

```
import { Body, Param, ParseIntPipe, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

export const Bind = () => Body(
  new ValidationPipe({transform: true}),
);

export const Id = () => Param('id', new ParseIntPipe());
```

And then use them as decorators:

```
import { Id, Bind } from './decorators';

// ... 

@Post(":id")
public create(@Id() id: number, @Bind() myData: MyClass) {
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I was answering the question and this came up in the meantime, lol I can confirm this does in fact work.

Comment: The given example did not work for me because I have a global validation pipe.

I spelled all of it out in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/9af97c36148673de596ecaa7e5eb6a0a.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code for custom nestjs body decorator with validate request

```
export const RBody = createParamDecorator(
  async (value: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    // extract headers
    const reqBody = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;
    // Convert headers to DTO object
    const dto = plainToInstance(value, reqBody);
    return await validateOrReject(dto).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(`Header validated successfully..${res}`);
        return dto;
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err.length > 0) {
          //Get the errors and push to custom array
          const validationErrors = err.map((obj, key) =>
            Object.values(obj.constraints)
          );
          throwException(validationErrors);
        }
      },
    );
    return dto;
  },
);
```